# Adding two or more fields based on condition and reclass sum in existing field using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a table that contains data that needs to be summed and the result needs to replace an existing value. I only want to sum the values if they are not -9999. The result would be put in the existing Total column.

Here is my table

| Total | D1 | D2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | -9999 | 5 |
| 5 | 5 | -9999 |

I am using ArcGIS Pro Python 3 Calculate Field on the Total column. I thought that the following would solve my issue, but I believe my condition is not being set properly. My result is only replacing Total with D1. The sum is not occurring.

Expression

```
calc(!D1!,!D2!)
```

Code Block

```
def calc(D1 , D2 ):
if (D1) != -9999:
    return (D1)
elif (D2) != -9999:
    return (D1 + D2)
else:
    return 0
```

This code is replacing a VB Script used in arcmap 10.8

```
a=0
If [d1]>=0 Then
a=a+ [d1]
End If
If [d2]>=0 Then
a=a+ [d2]
End If

Total = a
```

Is there a better way to write this script?

I could have up to 8 columns to sum.

```
def calc(D1 , D2 ):
if (D1) != -9999 and (D2) != -9999:
    return (D1 + D2)
elif (D1) != -9999 and (D2) == -9999:
    return (D1)
elif (D2) != -9999 and (D1) == -9999:
    return (D2)
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: The first thing your code says: "if D1 is valid then the total is D1"

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a code block for this, you can handle it with a single expression by using [6.13. Conditional expressions - Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions)

```py
(0 if !D1! == -9999 else !D1!) + (0 if !D2! == -9999 else !D2!)
```

**UPDATE:**

The [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/454982/196564) by [@Felix](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/34531/felixip) won't work with ArcGIS Pro because `<>` is no longer a valid comparison operator with Python 3.  That said, the overall approach scales cleaner if there are lots of columns invovled, but there are a couple of small gotchas to point out.

First, and I consider this a defect with Pro, is that one cannot use the not equals comparison operator, `!=`, in the expression for Calculate Field because Esri encloses field names in exclamations.  The parser for the expression can't handle having a non-paired exclamation, so an invalid syntax error is thrown.

Second, there is the question of how NULL should be handled.  Since SQL NULL gets converted to Python `None`, the presence of NULL will create a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'NoneType'` for the Python sum function.  So, NULL and -9999 both have to be handled in the expression.

The following handles NULL and -9999 as 0 and sums all the fields invovled while also addressing the parsing issue in the expression with exclamations:

```py
sum(0 if v==-9999 else v for v in (!D1!,!D2!,!D3!) if v is not None)
```

Since Python None is false-y, `if v is not None` can be shortened to just `if v`, but I left it in for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to write this script? I could have up to 8 columns to sum?

You could use a "starred arg" to accept any number of fields fed into the function which you can then iterate over:

```
def calc(*values):
    return sum(val if val != -9999 else 0 for val in values)
```

You don't mention what you want to happen in the case that all values are -9999.  Is it acceptable to return a total of 0 in this case, or should the total end up as -9999 as well?

If you don't want to return 0 when all columns are "nodata":

```
NODATA = -9999

def calc(*values):
    if all(val == NODATA for val in values):
        return NODATA
    return sum(val if val != NODATA else 0 for val in values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter without code block:

```
sum([v for v in [ !D1!, !D2!, !D3!, !D4!] if v <>-9999])
```

Yes "<>" instead of "!="

[image]

Comment: In Pro 3.1 this expression throws an `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` of `ERROR 000539:   File "<expression>", line 1 sum([v for v in [1,2,3] if v <>-9999])`